# Unwanted space in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
name = raw_input ("What's your name? ")
print "Hello",name, "!"
```

It returns the following:

```
What's your name? John
Hello John !
```

How do I make it so that the space between John and ! doesn't appear?

This is in Python-2.7 by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
print 'Hello %s!' %(name)
```

This will return

```
Hello John!
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print "Hello {0}!".format(name)
```

> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and should be preferred to the `%` formatting [...] in new code.

Comment: From python 2.7 you don't need the index inside the {}

Comment: @Nagasaki45: True, but the introduction of indices was one of the major advantages of the new format (explicit is better than implicit). I always use them for clarity even if I don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

Use format string:

```
print "Hello %s!"%name
```

Answer (score 0):

since your name variable itself is a string you can use these instead:

> print "hello"+name+"!"

or if it was't you can cast it to string using the `str()` function.